# Get bash date in 2023-04-03T23:59:59.000Z format

Tags: bash, shell

How to get the bash date in the below format

```
2023-04-03T23:59:59.000Z
```

I tried to concatenate strings but it doesn't look clean approach

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like below using `date` command:

```
date -u +"%FT%T.%3NZ"
```

**Explanation**:

```
-u flag tells date to use the UTC timezone
%F specifier is a shorthand for %Y-%m-%d
%T specifier is a shorthand for %H:%M:%S
%3N specifier represents the milliseconds in the current time
Z at the end indicates that the time is in UTC.
```

Comment: Note that the `%N` specifier (as in `%3N`) is nonstandard. I think it's a GNUism, so it'll generally work on Linuxes, but maybe not other OSes.

Comment: There is no such thing as "bash date command".